# found an error while proceeding to delivery order in odoo v9

Tags: location, odoo, product, warehouse

In odoo v9 when proceeding to delivery order of a respected product , giving me an error

[image]

so , what can I do to proceed my flow further
I have installed db without demo data
give me steps

Comment: what did you do.? I mean please give some steps to reproduce.? did you edited any code.?

Comment: try with latest pull of Odoo 9.

Comment: it's comming in a latest version dude hehehe

Comment: If it is appearing in latest version then dude this is not the right place to post issue, report here https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues ;)

Comment: k thanks for your support